# Write cache on local Windows 10 machine for asynchronous transfer to NAS?

Tags: windows, nas, streaming, cache, smb

I have an application that generates a stream of data as a single file. The amount of generated data is variable, but in average wouldn't nearly saturate my network or NAS speeds. However, there can be peaks for a few seconds that totally go above what's possible.

I don't have control over the application's behavior, which is just dropping data if the transfer can't keep up. If I generate the data stream onto my local SSD or even HDD, which is way slower than my NAS, everything is fine. I guess the latter one results from Windows' behavior of internally caching write operations in RAM. Is there some way to get this enabled for write operations on my NAS, too? Or are there other solutions available that would be able to solve this problem?

Also the whole data stream wouldn't fit on my SSD or even HDD, so just dumping it there and copying or syncing it later/asynchronous isn't an option for me. Ideally, if at all, I'd just want the non-synced portion of the file to reside somewhere on my local machine.

I am using Windows 10 Pro on my local machine. The NAS is a DS220+ and mounted via SMB.

Comment: Probably a long shot, but I think your description might implicate buffering behavior, and there is a way to bypass one (some?) using (on the client) `net use /writethrough` or `New-SMBMapping -UseWriteThrough`. Might look into that.

Comment: Enabling writethrough doesn't help, if not even worsens the problem. I already tried that and probably should have included it in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Windows uses cache memory for all file writes, which also pertains to
files residing on network shares.
Cache memory is important - if it is not large enough
for containing the data generated during these few seconds of
peak activity, the best solution would be to increase
the amount of RAM in the computer until it can contain it all,
catching up with writing it out when activity calms down.

You could also increase the size of the pagefile, so the RAM could
swap out more. Insure that the pagefile is on the SSD rather than the HDD.

You could try to improve the network speed with the aim of helping
Windows to empty the RAM faster toward the NAS, therefore postponing
the time that the RAM will fill up.

The following operations might help (or not). You would need to
try them and see. A good test might be measuring the speed of a
large file-copy to the NAS (larger than the RAM).

- Invest in a faster network adapter, if the NAS supports it
- Configure in Windows and in the NAS the network adapters
  [jumbo frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jumbo_frame),
  receive buffers, and interrupt moderation rate.
  On Windows, this is done in Device Management, right-click the network
  adapter, Properties, Advanced tab. The available settings depend
  on the adapter and the driver.
  Receive buffers might be more important on the NAS side, and this is
  done via `modprobe` or `ethtool`, depending on the adapter.
- Turn off the Windows firewall and disable the anti-virus.
- Use NFS for better performance. See the article
  [Network share: Performance differences between NFS & SMB](https://ferhatakgun.com/network-share-performance-differences-between-nfs-smb/).

You may find more details in the articles:

- [Configuring Your Computer and Network Adapters for Best Performance](https://supportcenter.pleora.com/s/article/Configuring-Your-Computer-and-Network-Adapters-for-Best-Performance-KBase).
- [Controlling write-through behaviors in SMB](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/storage-at-microsoft/controlling-write-through-behaviors-in-smb/ba-p/868341).

Comment: I have 64GB of RAM on my workstation (around ~8GB only are utilized by other things) and am connected via 1GBit to my NAS.  I already tried jumbo frames. The stream of data averages at a laughable 50MB/s with peaks around 200MB/s or more, but only for a second or two. My NAS can take data at a steady rate of 115MB/s. My workstation's HDD can only take data at 85MB/s but has no problems with the data stream because of Windows' write buffer. If I turn it off in the the drive policies I get the same problems as with the NAS. So how can I enable write buffers on my local machine for SMB shares?

Comment: Turning off the cache will slow everything down. But if you insist, you will find the info in [Controlling write-through behaviors in SMB](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/storage-at-microsoft/controlling-write-through-behaviors-in-smb/ba-p/868341).

Comment: If anything I want to increase the buffer, if that's even possible. Or even better: Have something that is equivalent to the local write cache in RAM on local drives. Have you even read my question/comment? How am I insisting? And on what anyway?

Comment: Your insistence is not always clear. Anyway, you don't need to increase the cache buffer - Windows will use as much of the RAM as it needs. As I wrote above, to increase the cache buffer you need to increase the RAM. Increasing the size of the pagefile might also help somewhat. But perhaps if you [disable write cache buffer flushing](https://superuser.com/questions/1214348/ssd-with-write-cache-buffer-flushing-turned-on-is-way-slower-in-as-ssd-but-not-c) the performance might improve.

Comment: Turning that off (or rather on) on network drives is not possible. The closest that can be done is disabling write through, which just makes matters worse.

Comment: To improve network speed, you could experiment with increasing [MaxDgramBuffering](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-client/networking/tcpip-and-nbt-configuration-parameters#optional-nbt-parameters-configurable-from-registry-editor) for the network send buffers. Or with [SizeReqBuf](https://serverfault.com/a/808751/18736). You could also verify that SMB3 is used and if the network driver on the client computer is the latest. In the end, there isn't a magic solution except throwing more hardware at the problem.

Comment: it is not clear to me that a filestream write from an arbitrary program is the same as ca file system file transfer. an example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14587494/writing-to-file-using-streamwriter-much-slower-than-file-copy-over-slow-network unfortunately, the op software is a black box

Comment: I think I'll try to use NFS instead of SMB ... seems like my best bet at this point.

Comment: NFS does offers a better performance. See the article [Network share: Performance differences between NFS & SMB](https://ferhatakgun.com/network-share-performance-differences-between-nfs-smb/).